# React: How can I show the selected value on userslist page?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to show the selected user on the Users List page but it throws an error. I have been trying this from many days but still I haven't yet figured out how I can achieve this. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance. I'm dropping three files AddUser.js,UsersList.js and useForm.js in code sandbox. Here's the link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-meadow-3j2xm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: setup a `sandbox`, so it will be easy for others to find your problem.

Comment: Where is your router ? I edit your sandbox. See App.js Now I added router to let you see how to have multiple pages with a router. This is just an example, Edituser can be in a different file. I took the code from https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

Comment: Also in UsesrList, each row of the table must have a unique key prop, see the console.